# Javascript variables/DOM Access not working on github pages

Tags: javascript

I am putting my basic projects on github pages, and my javascript does not seem to run. I searched extensively to try and solve this problem.

Basically, I have `onclick = function()` events in my HTML divs.

I also have javascript which saves DOM elements into variables like so.
`var selectorX = document.getElementById("X");
var selectorO = document.getElementById("O");`

When I log into my console, I keep getting messages like `selectorX is null`, and `selctorO is null`, etc.

This tells me that the javascript variables are not properly storing the html elemnets in the cache.

Does anyone have a familiarity with this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: I would have to post my entire program.

Comment: Means those elements don't exist when you run that code

Comment: Will this remain up? I am concerned that somebody else using the exact same search terms I did will not be able to find that above post. I even searched with terms including DOM access.